# PayPal Subscription Revise Error UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY

Tags: paypal, subscription

To revise a paypal subscription I use the following curl translated to php:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEP1G/revise  
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
-d '{
  "plan_id": "P-5ML4271244454362WXNWU5NQ"
}'
```

I replaced the plan-id and subscription id with variables. But I receive the following error:

```
{
   "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
   "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
   "debug_id":"1620f0049dfd6",
   "details":[
      {
         "issue":"PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS",
         "description":"Payment for the subscription is in progress."
      }
   ],
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
         "rel":"information_link",
         "method":"GET"
      }
   ]
}
```

I can't explain why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be it?

The error "PAYMENT_IN_PROGRESS" is returned if you attempt to revise the billing details for a subscription within 24 hours of the next scheduled billing.

As the profile you referenced "_____________" has a daily billing cycle, you won't be able to revise the billing details for this subscription.  Instead, you would need to cancel the existing subscription and create a new one with the relevant billing details which you wish to use.